# React wrong number operations results

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, operators

I'm new in React and I'm working in a simple app, and I need to read some numbers and make operations with them. The problem is that I always get odd results. For instance, debugging I got:

```
CALCULANDO 8 * 4 = 64
CALCULANDO 8 * 2 = 64
CALCULANDO 8 * 23 = 64
CALCULANDO 1 * 23 = 1
CALCULANDO 1 * 2 = 1
CALCULANDO 12 * 2 = 144
CALCULANDO 1 * 2 = 1
CALCULANDO 1 * 2 = 1
```

Looking at the output I assume that te values are being well read, and I have checked that I wait for the setState to finish, but I can't figure out the problem. The full code is:

```js
import Distribution from './Distribution';
import React, {Component} from 'react'; 
import NumberField from '../Components/NumberField';

class Binomial extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
      super(props);
      this.changeN = this.changeN.bind(this);
      this.changeP = this.changeP.bind(this);

      this.state={
        name: "Binomial",
        p: 0,
        n: 0,
        media: 0,
        varianza: 0
      }
    }

    calcularTodo(){
      this.calcularMedia();
      this.calcularVarianza();
    }

    calcularMedia(){
      if(this.state.p === 0|| this.state.n === 0)
        this.setState({media: 0})

      else{
        let result = Number(this.state.n) * Number(this.state.n); 
        console.log("CALCULANDO " + this.state.n + " * " + this.state.p + " = " + result)

        this.setState({media: result})
      }
    }

    calcularVarianza(){
      this.setState({varianza: 2})
    }

    render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <NumberField label={"p"} handleChange={this.changeP}/>
          <NumberField label={"n"} handleChange={this.changeN}/>
          <Distribution name={this.state.name} media={this.state.media} varianza={this.state.varianza}/>
        </div>
      )
    }

    changeP = async function (event){
      await this.setState({p: Number(event.target.value)});
      this.calcularTodo();
    }

    changeN = async function (event){
      await this.setState({n: Number(event.target.value)});
      this.calcularTodo();
    }
}

export default Binomial;
```

The other modules are:

```js
import React, {useState, Component} from 'react';
import {TextField} from "@material-ui/core";


class NumberField extends Component{
    
    render(){ 
        return (
        <TextField
          label="None"
          id="margin-none"
          label={this.props.label}
          variant="outlined"
          type={Number}
          onChange={this.props.handleChange}
        />
        )
    }
}

export default NumberField;
```

and

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'; 
import {Table} from '../Components/Table'
import NumberField from '../Components/NumberField'


class Distribution extends Component{
 
  constructor () {
    super();
  }

  render(){
    
    return(
      <div> 
      <this.props.name/>
      <Table _media={this.props.media} _varianza={this.props.varianza}/>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default Distribution;
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: you need to do it this way https://janhesters.com/updater-functions-in-setstate

Comment: Thanks for answering. You mean something like `state = {...prevState, ...{...prevState, media: result},};` ? I get the error: `'prevState' is not defined  no-undef`. Why do I have to do it that way, instead of just using await? It seems a bit tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving it a second look I think slate states is not the problem, the issue is you're trying to compute values that depends on others and update them at once, since react batches state updates it will take the previous values for calculations. You can solve it 2 ways, creating a updater function or using `componentDidUpdate`

updater function

```
class Binomial extends Component {
  ...

  updateState(updates) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const newState = { ...prevState, ...updates };
      return {
        ...newState,
        media: this.calcularMedia(newState),
        varianza: this.calcularVarianza(),
      };
    });
  }

  calcularMedia(state) {
    if (state.p === 0 || state.n === 0) return 0;

    let result = Number(state.n) * Number(state.n);
    console.log('CALCULANDO ' + state.n + ' * ' + state.p + ' = ' + result);

    return result;
  }

  calcularVarianza() {
    return 2;
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }

  changeP = async function(event) {
    await this.updateState({ p: Number(event.target.value) });
  };

  changeN = async function(event) {
    await this.updateState({ n: Number(event.target.value) });
  };
}
```

componentDidUpdate

```
class Binomial extends Component {
  ...

  componentDidUpdate(_prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.p !== this.state.p || prevState.n !== this.state.n) {
      this.calcularTodo();
    }
  }

  calcularTodo() {
    this.calcularMedia();
    this.calcularVarianza();
  }

  calcularMedia() {
    if (this.state.p === 0 || this.state.n === 0) this.setState({ media: 0 });
    else {
      let result = Number(this.state.n) * Number(this.state.n);
      console.log('CALCULANDO ' + this.state.n + ' * ' + this.state.p + ' = ' + result);

      this.setState({ media: result });
    }
  }

  calcularVarianza() {
    this.setState({ varianza: 2 });
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }

  changeP = async function(event) {
    await this.setState({ p: Number(event.target.value) });
  };

  changeN = async function(event) {
    await this.setState({ n: Number(event.target.value) });
  };
}
```

Comment: If it helps anyone, I found that in the `componentDidUpdate` version, is best to use `this.setState` inside it, instead of in the other functions. Otherwise, the problem persists.